# Using .sample with order specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very simple seed file set up to populate a model

```
year_group_array = ['Reception', 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6']

6.times { 
  year_group = YearGroup.create({
    name: year_group_array.sample
  })
}
```

This will ensure that all the items in the array are populated but not in any order (ideally I would like the entries in the order they appear in the array) and also I am hard-coding the number of times the loop has to run, how could I make it more dynamic so that it stops when there are no more items left in the array?

I'm just looking to get this performing a bit better, so that if I add anything to the array in future I won't have to count the number of items in the array and set the iteration value.

Comment: why don't try just: `year_group_array[0..5].each { |sample| YearGroup.create(name: sample) }`?

Comment: your right, i was trying to over complicate it, silly question to ask

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but just indexing a range will not sample the array. Sample takes a random element from the array. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: you are right josh, sample does take a random element from an array, but it was my understanding that when combined with 6.times, each random element would be unique,ensuring that each of my records in my array would be inserted into my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way to tie original arrays value to the output is to just enumerate the original array.

```
year_group_array = ['Reception', 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6']

year_group_array[0..5].each { |sample| YearGroup.create(name: sample) }
```

if you have to use a random value:

```
LIMIT = 6
source = year_group_array[0..LIMIT].dup
year_group_array[0..LIMIT].each { |sample| YearGroup.create(name: source.delete(rand(LIMIT))) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be answer. A pretty much simple approach from me.

```
year_group_array = ['Reception', 'Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6']

year_group_array.shuffle.each do |year|  
  year_group = YearGroup.create({
    name: year
  })
end
```

so Array#shuffle will do the trick. It will randomize the the index/position of object in the collection and Collection#each will keep collecting them to a block and create a record in no order and keep adding the record unless all the records are created.